# The Password match error is true still the error message does not get displayed

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

the password and confirmation dont match, the button is disabled if the form is invalid but still the message in the `<mat-error>` does not gets displayed

**Template file**

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
            <input type="password" formControlName="password" matInput required />

            <mat-error *ngIf="AuthForm.get('password').errors">Valid Password required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Password Confirmation</mat-label>
            <input type="password" formControlName="passwordConfirmation" matInput required />

            <mat-error *ngIf="AuthForm.get('password').touched && AuthForm.get('passwordConfirmation').touched && AuthForm.errors"> Passwords dont match!</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <button [disabled]="AuthForm.invalid" mat-flat-button color="primary">Register</button>
```

**External Class Validator**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Validator, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms'

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class MatchPassword implements Validator {
    validate(formGroup: FormGroup) {
       const passwordControl= formGroup.get('password');
       const passwordConfirmControl= formGroup.get('passwordConfirmation')
        if (passwordControl.value != passwordConfirmControl.value) {
            return { passwordsDontMatch: true }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Component class**

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {
  AuthForm = new FormGroup({

    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.minLength(10),
    Validators.maxLength(25)]),

    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4), 
    Validators.maxLength(20)]),

    passwordConfirmation: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, 
      Validators.minLength(4), 
      Validators.maxLength(20),
      ]
      ) 
  }, {validators : [this.MatchPassword.validate]})

  

  constructor( private MatchPassword: MatchPassword) { }
```

The message in the `<mat-error>` does not get displayed even if there is an error and the passwords dont match. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mat-error  AuthForm.get('passwordConfirmation').hasError('passwordsDontMatch')> Passwords dont match!</mat-error>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check current control errors instead of formGroup errors

Instead of this

```
*ngIf="
  AuthForm.get('password').touched && 
  AuthForm.get('passwordConfirmation').touched && 
  AuthForm.errors
"
```

Try this

```
*ngIf="
  AuthForm.get('password').touched && 
  AuthForm.get('passwordConfirmation').touched && 
  AuthForm.get('passwordConfirmation').errors
"
```

Also for convenience you can create `getter` for `passwordConfirmation` formControl

In your controller

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(){}

  get passwordConfirmation() {
    return this.AuthForm .get('passwordConfirmation')
  }

}
```

And use it in html

```
*ngIf="
  passwordConfirmation?.touched && 
  passwordConfirmation?.touched && 
  passwordConfirmation?.errors
"
```